# 301 redirection is not working in html website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I used this below code to redirect my website (**www.earabictoenglish.com**) but it is not working please help me to redirect it! my website developer is confused! Please rewrite and help me...i dont know what is the error ???

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^earabictoenglish.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.earabictoenglish.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.pages\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.pages$ http://www.earabictoenglish.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: why twice RewriteEngine ON?

Comment: what are you trying to capture in that THE_REQUEST line?

Comment: Actually, i am not aware of coding, I am just Arabic Translator, one of SEO person specialist gave this code to me. So, can anyone please rewrite it for my site and send me, please ? if you send the final coding I will tell my developer to upload it in domain root folder and I will check redirection. Thanks in advance

Comment: The first 4 lines seem to have the purpose to force www. in the url. **Question**: "does -is not working- mean you donot get redirected? or do you get en error message?

Comment: it was not redirected, but today we found it! Because my site was uploaded in Google app engine so I was not working but we fixed it, Thanks lot for your support! now you can check...www.earabictoenglish.com